# What do brackets do to cause "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"?

Tags: python

The first code runs correctly but the second one does not. What is the problem here?

```
>>> print("%d" %100,100)
100 100
>>> print("%d" %(100,100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#96>", line 1, in <module>
    print("%d" %(100,100))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   ```print("%d" % (100, 100))``` expects you to have two parameters.. like ```%d %d``` in the print format.

Answer (score 0):

With the parentheses, you're passing two arguments to the string formatting: `100, 100`. That could work if you had two placeholders, for example:

```
>>> print("%d %d" % (100, 100))
100 100
```

Without the parentheses, you're only passing one argument: `100`, which, in this context, is equivalent to a tuple containing `100`, i.e. `(100,)`

In other words, the parentheses change the order of operations.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
print("%d" %(100,100))
```

To

```
print("%d" %100,100)
```

It will solve your problem.
Thank You.